# validation rule to allow an upgrade of priority, but not downgrade

Tags: validation-rule

I have a need to have users be able to change a Priority but only if its being upgraded. Our priorities are
P1
P2
P3
P4

I don't want certain users to be able to move a case from a P1 down to a P4, but I DO want them to be able to move a P4 up to a P1. How would I accomplish this?

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you stuck? Please [edit] your question to include that. Even if it doesn't work, it can help people write more tailored answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the old and new values of the **Priority** field and prevent the users from changing the priority to a lower value.

You can use something like this in your validation rule formula:

```
AND(
    ISCHANGED(Priority),
    CASE(Priority,
         "P1", 1,
         "P2", 2,
         "P3", 3,
         "P4", 4,
         0) <
    CASE(PRIORVALUE(Priority),
         "P1", 1,
         "P2", 2,
         "P3", 3,
         "P4", 4,
         0)
)
```

This formula will evaluate to true if the **Priority** field is changed and the new value is lower than the old value, based on the numerical order of the priorities. You can also add a custom error message to inform the users why they cannot change the priority to a lower value.

Answer (score 1):

Starting with a Custom Permission that you can assign to profiles/permission sets, your validation rule would be:

```
AND(
  NOT($Permission.Can_Downgrade_Priority),
  CASE(Priority__c,
    "P1", 1,
    "P2", 2,
    "P3", 3,
    "P4", 4, 0
  ) >
  CASE(PRIORVALUE(Priority__c),
    "P1", 1,
    "P2", 2,
    "P3", 3,
    "P4", 4, 0
  )
)
```

This will throw an error if they don't have permission, and if the new priority is higher than the old priority.